# jQuery AJAX Load Method - Delay

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'll admit that I'm pretty new web development (only been coding for about a year) and especially green when it comes to JS / jQuery.

A specific web page I've built loads different data based on hovering over certain categories: country clubs, resorts, hotels, etc.  When I built the site on my local machine, the javascript function was super quick. However, on the live site, it has a long delay before the data swap happens.

The URL is: http://preferredparkingsolutions.com/client_list.html

Which links to a javascript function at: http://preferredparkingsolutions.com/scripts/clientHover.js

Which replaces the display div (#client_list) by pulling data from a text file.

Is there a better / faster way of doing this?

Comment: roughly less than half a second, doesn't seem that slow to me

Comment: It took 3 mins to me ;)..Looks like there is some problem.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it's not that bad of a delay? It just seems like forever to me because on my machine it's damn near instantaneous.

Comment: Any delay is too long in this situation - the user expects something instantaneously to happen on hover.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking of reusing the basic operating concept for other sites and I'm thinking if it's more than a simple div being replaced it may take even longer.

Comment: @user1515551 How much time does this take 'client_list.inc.html' to load in your browser .. It is fast indeed i suggest you to getrid of onload option ..Look at Uktanos anwser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this could be optimised by loading the content in up-front and caching it. Currently you are doing a HTTP request each for each and every hover - even if the user has hovered over that element before, since the AJAX responses aren't being cached. Doing this would be your quickest win.

However, I can't see any case at all for having the content live externally. Is there any reason you're against having the content physically in the page and just using show/hide methods? There's various benefits to this - SEO, for one thing, since Google will find the content.

Comment: No, I think that's probably what I need to do. I have the tendency to break things off into as many self-contained chunks as possible because that's kind of how my brain works, which is why I segregated the content into an external file.

Comment: We've all been there. There's sometimes reasons to do this - particularly with aps, or where your data is returned from a web service. In your case, though, just stick it in your main HTML. There's always server-side options (PHP etc) if you want your content to live separate from your physical pages.

Comment: Aha! Now it's working exactly the way I'd envisioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

this is the external page you are loading http://preferredparkingsolutions.com/client_list.inc.html and the content looks little and looks like its a static page then why not just load every thing upfront and then just hide and show div's ? as Utkanos suggested you will aslo have a SEO benifit and also its HTTP request each for each and every hover. if you still want to load it externally lost load it once and cache it and use the cached version to hide and show divs.

Comment: Yep. That seems like the way to go. Thanks guys.